# how to access "this" from component method

Tags: reactjs

I've got this little component which is supposed to post to the server with each change:

```
class SelectElement extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            optionList: []
        };
    }

    finalize() {
        // this means "window" in this case... so all the code below barfs:
        let key = this.props.inputName;
        let val = this.state.text;
        let postObj = {};
        postObj[key] = val;
        console.dir(postObj);
        $.post($.endPoints.saveCallField, postObj).done(function (response) {
            console.dir(response);
        });
    }

    render() {
        this.props.options.forEach(option =>
            this.state.optionList.push(<OptionElement value={option} text={option }/>)
        );
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <select className="form-control callField" name={this.props.inputName}
                        onChange={this.finalize}>
                    {this.state.optionList}
                </select>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

I can't get access to "this" where "this" is the SelectElement itself. I need the state and props. How can I get it?

Comment: change `finalize() {` to `finalize = () => {` or in your constructor do `this.finalize = this.finalize.bind(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of these:

1. `this.finalize = this.finalize.bind(this);` in constructor
2. `onChange={this.finalize.bind(this)}`
3. `onChange={e => this.finalize(e)}`
4. `finalize = () => {};`

You can read more about the pros and cons [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've identified the issue. When the `finalize()` method is called, `this` is bound to the window.

You can solve the issue by binding the function in the constructor. For example:

```
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                optionList: []
            };
            this.finalize = this.finalize.bind(this);
        }
```

It's generally better to bind in the constructor than to bind in the `render` method, because if you call `bind` in the render method, you are generating a new function each time.

For more information, take a look at this: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56